# How to guess a change of variable for an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is related about how to guess what change of variable to make in an ODE? For example, we have $$\varepsilon^2y(x)''=axy(x)$$ where $\varepsilon\ll1$, $a$ is constant and $x$ is the independent variable.

Here we can make a change of variable $t=\varepsilon^{-2/3}a^{1/3}x$ to get $$y''(t)=ty(t)$$ which is an Airy equation with a known behaviour. The problem is that if you give me the first equation and then you tell me to find a change of variable in order to get the Airy equation I couldn't know how to do it in a sistematic way, perhaps I would find the solution but after a lot of trial and error attempts.

Do you know any trick or method to guess the change of variable in a fast way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of substitution, it is almost always a good start if you leave one or two parameters in your substitution, which you can then adjust to get desired cancellations.  In the equation you had, assuming that the $y'' = xy$ form were to be recognized as looking someting liike Airy's equation, the first thing to try would be
$$
x= \kappa t
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\kappa} \frac{dy}{dt} \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{\kappa^2} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \\
\frac{\epsilon^2}{\kappa^2} \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = a \kappa t y \\
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{a \kappa^3}{\epsilon^2} ty(t)
$$
and you can set $\kappa$ so as to make $$\frac{a \kappa^3}{\epsilon^2} = 1
\\ \kappa = \epsilon^{2/3} a^{-1/3}$$

You can then pretend you decided to make that transformation as some inspired guess; but really, you kind of "looked ahead."